# Which of the following symbols not used in ERD?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Which of the following symbols not used in ERD?
A- Rectangle
B- Circle
C- Oval
D- Cube
E- Pentagon
F- Diamand

Answer (score 0):

It's both `D- Cube` and  `E- Pentagon`; those symbols are not used in Entity relationship Diagram to depict anything.
See [ER Diagram Symbols and Meaning](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ER-diagram-symbols-and-meaning) for yourself.